# Redis Data Persistance

Tags: python, redis

I want to store the Redis data in memory to Hard or any other in my server if sudden shutdowns or restarts happen and restore after it restarts. Are there a way to do it in Python without slowing the read/write on Redis?

Answer (score 0):

Redis supports two types of persistence:

- RDB persistence: method that performs point-in-time snapshots of yourdataset of specified intervals
- AOF persistence: that method logs every write operation received by the server, which can then be played back at startup, reconstructing the original dataset.

You can use these methods to persist your data to disk without significantly slowing down the read/write operations on Redis.
This example show you how to connect a Redis server and set up data persistence using Python and the redis-py library1:

```
import redis

# Connect to Redis server
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

# Set key-value pair
r.set('foo', 'bar')

# Save data to disk
r.bgsave()  # This will save data in the background
```

bgsave() is used to save the data to disk in the background. This means that Redis can continue to handle requests while it writes the data to disk, which helps to maintain high performance.